# Not able to convert Bitmap to perfect Base64 String in Android?

Tags: android, base64

I am working on an application in which I need to capture an Image from camera. After capture, I have to **convert the Bitmap to Base64**. After converting to Base64, I have to send that String to SERVER. I am using below code for this task:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**Problem :** When I convert that Base64 to image, I am getting INCOMPLETE IMAGE. The same result is happening over server where my image is not perfectly re-constructed from Base64 String.

Please suggest me the solution. I have already search a-lot and getting same code which I am using right now.

**Edited: please see the below incomplete Image**

[image]

Code use to capture the Image:

```
intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Comment: you getting *INCOMPLETE IMAGE* as what?

Comment: is the problem occuring for all images or on some specific one?

Comment: From the base64 string, only 25% image is generated...and this is happening with all the images

Comment: See I have posted the image also...The size of the image is exact to the orignal...but only 25% above part is generated.. rest not completed

Comment: are you changing the size of image with `BitmapFactoty.Options` *options.inSampleSize*?

Comment: http://megacodearchive.com/Page/Content/51683/Base64-encoderdecoder

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i solved it. the problem was in the storing of the base64 string on the database. my column was declare as "TEXT" and it cuts the other picture's parts because the lenght of the string. so i changes it to "LONGTEXT" and now it's work perfectly!

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you made my day. I was also facing the same problem so I converted my "BLOB" datatype to "LONGBLOB".

Answer (score 0):

> When I convert that Base64 to image, I am getting INCOMPLETE IMAGE

Try to do this with your image `Bitmap` and check if something is not as expected:

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); //or whatever image you want
Log.d(TAG, "original bitmap byte count: " + originalBitmap.getByteCount());

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
originalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
Log.d(TAG, "byte array output stream size: " + baos.size());

byte[] outputByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
Log.d(TAG, "output byte array length: " + outputByteArray.length);

String base64EncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(outputByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d(TAG, "base64 encoded string length: " + base64EncodedString.length());

byte[] inputByteArray = Base64.decode(base64EncodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d(TAG, "input byte array length: " + inputByteArray.length);

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputByteArray);
Log.d(TAG, "byte array input stream size: " + bais.available());

Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);
Log.d(TAG, "decoded bitmap byte count: " + decodedBitmap.getByteCount());

Log.d(TAG, "decoded bitmap same as original bitmap? " + decodedBitmap.sameAs(originalBitmap));
```

If all is ok then the problem is not the base64 encoding. Let me know!