# Encode Image to string using Base64 format

Tags: android, base64

I am sending image string from android to Php server using Base64 format. But at server end, full Image is not displaying. Only some upper part of Image is displaying. I used following code below

```
Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);           
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); 
    byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

    String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
    System.out.println("image_str >>>> " + image_str );
```

Here I am capturing photo then sending to server. I also reffer [Image not encoded successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991926/not-able-to-convert-bitmap-to-perfect-base64-string-in-android) but I didnt get solution.

Thank you.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Download Base64 class from here [Base64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-base64/) and replace it and try it again

Comment: Which class should I replace ? I mean, are u talking about library.?

Comment: Instead of using android.util.base64 use the base64 class from this library